# flutter build apk giving error "Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'." on jenkins

Tags: android, flutter, dart, jenkins, gradle

I am getting below exception when i build my flutter project on jenkins

```
C:\ProgramData\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\automated test app>flutter build apk 

Building with sound null safety 

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                        
Parameter format not correct -

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'.
> Multiple task action failures occurred:
> A failure occurred while executing 
 com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable
  > Android resource compilation failed
    ERROR:C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\846e5094a0f0114af067375a609d094e\transformed\core-1.6.0\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\notification_bg_normal.9.png: AAPT: error: file not found.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable
  > Android resource compilation failed
    ERROR:C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\846e5094a0f0114af067375a609d094e\transformed\core-1.6.0\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\notification_bg_low_normal.9.png: AAPT: error: file not found.

 > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable
  > Android resource compilation failed
    ERROR:C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\846e5094a0f0114af067375a609d094e\transformed\core-1.6.0\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\notification_bg_low_pressed.9.png: AAPT: error: file not found.
```

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

```
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 25s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           86.2s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: try flutter clean and do flutter pub get and build again

Comment: already tried this

Comment: I have same problems but for me it's with gitlab ci

Answer (score 1):

I am faced with this problem with **Gitlab ci/Runner** on **Windows 10** and i stucked with all day.
The problem is that I have not installed **Gitlab-Runner** with privileges **windows** with my user account before :

```
cd C:\GitLab-Runner
.\gitlab-runner.exe install
.\gitlab-runner.exe start
```

But after, I installed Gitlab-Runner **using my user account**. The problems no longer occurs.

```
cd C:\GitLab-Runner
.\gitlab-runner.exe install --user ".\USERR" --password "MYPASSWORD"
.\gitlab-runner.exe start
```

So, I think maybe your problem is that you are not running the script with a privileges.
The fact that I saw this because when I tried to access the image file.
For example : `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\846e5094a0f0114af067375a609d094e\transformed\core-1.6.0\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\notification_bg_normal.9.png`

I'm not able to reach the `"C:\Windows\System32"` without accepting the privileges administrator windows.
But if I accept as administrator, I can find the image file.